# Setting nested object property by string path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 3 select boxes, and I would like them to reset a certain field on select. How can I make it dynamic, so that it is reusable?

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
v-on:select="getDate('{{ route('api.v1.get.date') }}', 'input1', ['form.company.input2', 'form.company.input3'], $event)"

getDate(url, obj, obj2, event){

     let current = this

     current[obj] = ''
     current[obj2[0]] = ''
     current[obj2[1]] = ''

}
```

When `obj` is at the root level of the Vue instance (i.e., `current[obj]`), it sets the property correctly; but not when `obj` is a nested object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) do not allow nested *object paths*, which is what you have in the dot-separated string. By using that string, you're actually creating a property on the root Vue instance instead of setting a nested property, similar to this:

```
this['form.company.input2'] = ''  // XXX: creates `form.company.input2` prop
this.form.company.input2 = ''     // sets `input2`
```

To set the object value by path, you could create a method that uses the object path to navigate the current Vue instance's data properties via `this`:

```js
methods: {
  getDate(url, obj, obj2, event) {
    this.setValue(obj, '')
    this.setValue(obj2[0], '')
    this.setValue(obj2[1], '')
  },
  setValue(path, value) {
    let obj = this
    const parts = path.split('.')
    while (parts.length > 1 && obj.hasOwnProperty(parts[0])) {
      obj = obj[parts.shift()]
    }
    obj[parts[0]] = value
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      input1: 'input1',
      form: {
        company: {
          input2: 'input2',
          input3: 'input3'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDate(url, obj, obj2, event) {
      this.setValue(obj, '')
      this.setValue(obj2[0], '')
      this.setValue(obj2[1], '')
    },
    setValue(path, value) {
      let obj = this
      const parts = path.split('.')
      while (parts.length > 1 && obj.hasOwnProperty(parts[0])) {
        obj = obj[parts.shift()]
      }
      obj[parts[0]] = value
    },
    route(prop) {
      return prop
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="input1">
  <input v-model="form.company.input2">
  <input v-model="form.company.input3">

  <button @click="getDate(route('api.v1.get.date'), 'input1', ['form.company.input2', 'form.company.input3'], $event)">
    Reset data
  </button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use a library (such as `lodash`'s [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set)):

```js
methods: {
  getDate(url, obj, obj2, event) {
    _.set(this, obj, '')
    _.set(this, obj2[0], '')
    _.set(this, obj2[1], '')
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      input1: 'input1',
      form: {
        company: {
          input2: 'input2',
          input3: 'input3'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDate(url, obj, obj2, event) {
      _.set(this, obj, '')
      _.set(this, obj2[0], '')
      _.set(this, obj2[1], '')
    },
    route(prop) {
      return prop
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="input1">
  <input v-model="form.company.input2">
  <input v-model="form.company.input3">

  <button @click="getDate(route('api.v1.get.date'), 'input1', ['form.company.input2', 'form.company.input3'], $event)">
    Reset data
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `this.$set` function as follows:

```
  this.$set(current,obj,'');
 this.$set(current,obj2[0],'');
 this.$set(current,obj2[1],'');
```

learn more about that function [`here`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: Seems i'm encountering this error when using set method, the data has already been set yet i still get this error "[Vue warn]: Avoid adding reactive properties to a Vue instance or its root $data at runtime - declare it upfront in the data option."

Comment: `current[obj]` is passed via props?

Comment: the function is in the same instance, i passed it on v-select "form.compay.input2"

Answer (score 0):

This library allows you to use nested object paths.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-data-object-path

Your excerpt would look like this:

```
v-on:select="getDate('{{ route('api.v1.get.date') }}', 'input1', ['form.company.input2', 'form.company.input3'], $event)"

getDate(url, obj, obj2, event){

     let current = this

     current.$op.set(obj, '')
     current.$op.set(obj2[0], '')
     current.$op.set(obj2[1], '')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **getting** or **setting** nested values inside an `object` having the path as `string`

```
function getNestedValue(obj, path){
    return path.split('.').reduce((o,i)=> o[i] || '', obj)
}

function setNestedValue(obj, path, value) {
    let i;
    path = path.split('.');
    for (i=0;i<path.length-1;i++) obj = obj[path[i]];
    obj[path[i]] = value
}

const obj = { a:{ b: [{c: 1 },{ d: 2 }] }}

setNestedValue(obj,'a.b.0.c',3)
console.log(getNestedValue(obj, 'a.b.0.c'))  // 3
```