# js object update nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "language": "eng",
  "plugins": {
    "search": false,
    "import-xml": false,
    "export-xml": false,
    "import-pdf": false,
    "export-pdf": false
  },
  "tabs": {
    "general": {
      "arm": "Գլխավոր",
      "rus": "Главный",
      "eng": "General",
      "documentTitle": {
        "arm": "Փաստաթղթի Անվանումը",
        "rus": "Заголовок Документа",
        "eng": "Document Title"
      },
      "sections": {
        "14656691": {
          "type": "field-section",
          "title": "",
          "elements": {
          },
          "collapse": false
        },
        "06558184": {
          "type": "table-section",
          "title": "",
          "elements": {
          },
          "collapse": false
        }
      }
    },
    "custom-19588079": {
      "arm": "Custom",
      "rus": "Custom",
      "eng": "Custom",
      "documentTitle": {
        "arm": "Փաստաթղթի Անվանումը",
        "rus": "Заголовок Документа",
        "eng": "Document Title"
      },
      "sections": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example I want to add new object in general sections object. How can I do it?

I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work properly:

```
let config = {} (my object);

config = {...config.general.sections, ...{new object}}
```

but `config` result is `config.general.sections` object.

Comment: Why is that surprising? You're explicitly replacing `config` with a shallow copy of `config.general.sections` plus whatever's in "new object".

Comment: Update it as ```config.tabs.general.sections = {...config.tabs.general.sections, ...{new object}}```

Comment: How about `Object.assign(config.tabs.general.sections, newObject)`?

Comment: same result the problem is in localStorage that json is on localStorage

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
let config = {} (my object);
let newObject = {"newKey":"newValue"};
config.general.newSection = newObject;
console.log(config);
```

Or try this:

```
let config = {} (my object);
let newObject = {"newKey":"newValue"};
config['general']['newSection'] = newObject;
console.log(config);
```

I home it's works

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way, to merge with a new section and to reassign it:

```
config.tabs.general.sections = {
  ...config.tabs.general.sections,
  newSection: {},
};
```

Here is a good explanation https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

This code is very useful if you know the path to the wanted value.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66440832/1602673